# using devise how do i keep a user logged in past closing the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails app using devise and even with the remember me button clicked when i close the browser and reopen it it loses all history of the user ever being logged in.

The session should persist well beyond that. How do i change this?

I am not using timeoutable or anything that auto logs the user out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the 'Rememberable' module in Devise?

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable

Answer (score 0):

On the user Model =>

```
:rememberable
```